# iPhone won't turn on and I am unable to put it into DFU mode

Tags: ios, iphone

My iPhone 5C has no battery and won't turn on, I've been told to put it into DFU mode to reset it, however I can't do that because I need to hold down my Home button which is broken! Anyone know what I can do? 😨

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you really can do is get someone to replace the home button ribbon cable for you, sorry.

The physical home button is likely not the problem. On the other side of the iPhone screen is a sensor which detects if the button was pressed. This is the likely the problem, and you can find them on eBay as a home button as a home button ribbon cable. However, it may be that the connector terminals on headphone jack are no good and that needs repair. I'd strongly advise trying to find a pro to do this repair for you, the iPhone 5C is no fun to work on, the screen is hard to reconnect "just right". So, if you have little to no experience in iPhone repair, you'd be better off seeking a pro.

Comment: Can I get home buttons anywhere ?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Good idea, I put it in the answer, thanks.

Comment: Why would the OP have to reset the iPhone in DFU mode in the first place? The question is kind of unclear as to what exactly is happening. If they can Actually get the phone to power up and login again, then they can go into settings under accessibility and turn on Assistive touch, which will give them access to an on screen proxy for all of the buttons around the Phone. I turned mine on because I have an iPhone 5 that was recalled for the Power button. The only thing I can't do is restart the phone after a power down unless I plug it in to a Lightning Cable.

Comment: I need to restart my I phone but the home button has broke and I've got no battery